# How to find a special word inside a file using Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a bunch of `.java` files in a directory and I want to compile all of them to `.class` files via python code.

As you know, the `Javac` command line tool is the tool that I must use and it require the name of `.java` files to be equal with the class name. Unfortunately for my `.java` files, it isn't. I mean they have different random names that are not equal with their class names.

So I need to extract the name of classes from the contents of `.java` files. It was simple if the line of class definition was specified, but it isn't. The `.java` file may contains some comments in the top that may contain *class* or *package* words too.

The question is how I can extract package and class name of each file?

For example this is contents of one of them:

```java
//This is a sample package that its class name is HelloWorldApplet. in this package we blah blah blah and this class blah blah blah.
package helloWorldPackage;
//This is another comment that may or may not have the word "package" and "class" inside.
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISO7816;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.Util;
/* this is also a multi line comment. blah blah blah package, blah blah blah package ... */
public class HelloWorldApplet extends Applet 
{
    private static final byte[] helloWorld = {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};
    private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;
    private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
        {
        new HelloWorldApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
        }

    public void process(APDU apdu) 
        {
        if (selectingApplet()) 
            {
            return;
            }

        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
        byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);

        if (CLA != HW_CLA)
            {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }

        switch ( INS ) 
            {
            case HW_INS:
                getHelloWorld( apdu );
                break;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
            }
        }

    private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu)
        {
        byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
        short length = (short) helloWorld.length;
        Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(helloWorld, (short)0, buffer, (short)0, (short) length);
        apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0, length);
        }
}
```

How can I extract package name (i.e. `helloWorldPackage`) and class name(i.e `HelloWorldApplet`) of each file?

Note that, the `.java` files may have different classes inside, but I need the name of that class that extends `Applet` only.

**Update:**

I tried the followings, but they didn't worked (Python 2.7.10):

```
import re

prgFile = open(r"yourFile\New Text Document.txt","r")
contents = prgFile.read()

x = re.match(r"(?<=class)\b.*\b(?=extends Applet)",contents)
print x
x = re.match(r"^(public)+",contents)
print x
x = re.match(r"^package ([^;\n]+)",contents)
print x
x = re.match(r"(?<=^public class )\b.*\b(?= extends Applet)",contents)
print x
```

Output:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
None
None
None
None
>>>
```

Comment: As simple as [`^package ([^;\n]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aU5kO7/1) ?

Comment: Is that the file that you need? Try printing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases a simple regex will work.

If you want to be 100% certain I suggest using a full-blown Java parser like [javalang](https://github.com/c2nes/javalang) to parse each file, then walk the AST to pull out the class name.

Something like

```
import glob
import javalang

# look at all .java files in the working directory
for fname in glob.glob("*.java"):
    # load the sourcecode
    with open(fname) as inf:
        sourcecode = inf.read()

    try:
        # parse it to an Abstract Syntax Tree
        tree = javalang.parse.parse(sourcecode)
        # get package name
        pkg = tree.package.name

        # look at all class declarations
        for path, node in tree.filter(javalang.tree.ClassDeclaration):
            # if class extends Applet
            if node.extends.name == 'Applet':
                # print the class name
                print("{}: package {}, main class is {}".format(fname, pkg, node.name))

    except javalang.parser.JavaSyntaxError as je:
        # report any files which don't parse properly
        print("Error parsing {}: {}".format(fname, je))
```

which gives

```
sample.java: package helloWorldPackage, main class is HelloWorldApplet
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works for me. `(?<=^public class )\b.*\b(?= extends Applet)`.

The way to use it correctly:

```
re.compile(ur'(?<=^public class )\b.*\b(?= extends Applet)', re.MULTILINE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with the following regex:

```
import re
string = your_string_here
classes = [x.strip() for x in re.findall(r'^(?:public class|package) ([^;]+?)(?=extends|;)', string, re.MULTILINE)]
# look for public class or package at the start of the line 
# then anything but a semicolon
# make sure the match is immediately followed by extends or a colon
print classes
# ['helloWorldPackage', 'HelloWorldApplet']
```